# Nokogiri Node Set

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to use Nokogiri to scrape a web page.  Right now, I am able to set a variable links to the following on a web page:

```
links = page.css('.item_inner')
```

and links is a:

```
Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
```

Then I iterate through this NodeSet(links):

```
links.each{|link| puts link.css('.details a')}
```

In order to get some more information.  But now the method above's class is now a:

```
Fixnum
```

and returns a list of (I'm not sure exactly what they are returning but it looks like a list of these:

```
<a se:clickable:target="true" href="/nyc/sale/1056207-coop-150-sullivan-street-soho-new-york?featured=1">150 Sullivan Street #34</a>
```

Now I know that there are key/value pairs within this but I am unable to access them at this point.  How can I access say the href here and the actual name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a *single* link as a node, its href is `link['href']` and so forth, and the link text ("150 Sullivan Street") is its `content`.

NOTE: A `css` search always yields what is effectively an array of found nodes (actually a NodeSet). If you are quite sure that there is only one of something to be found by your search, you can skip past that by using `at_css` instead, thus yielding a single node.

Comment: are you saying in order to get the href from each node I do something like links.each{|link| puts link.css('.details a')['href']}?

Comment: No, because `link.css` is itself an array. You have to cycle through those results too.

Comment: `links.each{|link| puts link.at_css('.details a')['href']}` is effectively giving me the href but `links.each{|link| puts link.at_css('.details a')['content']}` is giving me back nothing

Comment: I didn't say it was its `['content']`. I said it was its `content`. - Reading [the docs](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) would help you too; this is all right there.